# Printing the returned data as a link in mysql

Tags: php, hyperlink

There are two columns in the database as social media platform name and link. When I pull the data from php, I want it to go to the link when the facebook one is clicked.

```
<div>
    <?php foreach ($socialmedia as $sm){?>
    <span><?= $sm->platform ?><i> -> </i><?= $sm->link ?></span><?php } ?> </div>
```

Comment: And what's the problem with just surrounding it with `<a href>` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have a link stored in your database, and you want to display it yout HTML via PHP.

Then you'll need this HTML tag:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Using you provided code it would be something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $sm->link ?>">Facebook</a>
```

EDIT:
Reading your comment, you just need to add it like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $sm->link ?>"><?php echo $sm->platform ?></a>
```

This way you display the link and the name of the platform too.

Comment: No. This is not what I want. The platform name and link address are kept in relation to the table. The "Facebook" data must also come from the database.

Comment: Yes. That's the answer. Thank you sir.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it :). pls mark the answer as accepted. I'm trying to get some reputation to be able to upvote answers that helped me before. Best regards.

Comment: Note that this is a potential security issue. Use htmlspecialchars on the individual variables.

Comment: But printing your own data shouldn't be a problem right? I understand the issue when it comes to use data you've taken from input fields in your site. I'm I right?

Comment: Ok. I done. I also using htmlspecialchars. Thank you.